# SQL - Query to split original sort

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope my title is ok as I really don’t know how to call it.

Anyway, I have a table with the following :

- ID - Num (Primary Key)
- Category - VarChar
- Name - VarChar
- DateForName - Date

Data looks like that :

```
1  100  111  31/12/2017
2  101  210  30/12/2017
3  100  112  29/12/2017
4  101  203  27/12/2017
5  100  117  20/12/2017
6  103  425  08/12/2017
```

To generate this table, I just sorted by date DESC.

Is there a way to add a new column with the order per Category like :

```
1  100|1
2  101|1
3  100|2
4  101|2
5  100|3
6  103|1
```

Max

Comment: Why the Category aren't int ? But you can just set `GROUP BY Category` at the end of your SQL request

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (@Yogesh' answer is great, but not supported by all dbms products.)

Comment: Hello, i am using SQL Server. Please note that Category cannot be set as number, it is a varchar in my real data.

Answer (score 3):

You want *analytical* function `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by Category order by date desc) Seq
      from table 
      ) t
order by id;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL has a couple options for you to add a column that is populated with a ranking of the rows based on the category and id columns.

If you just want to add a column to the select statement, I recommend using the RANK() function.
See more details here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

For your current table, try the following select statement:

```
SELECT
[ID],
[Category],
[Name],
[DateForName],
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Category] ORDER BY [DateForName] DESC) AS [CategoryOrder]
FROM [TableName]
```

Alternatively, if you want to add a permanent column (aka a field) to the existing table, I recommend treating this as a calculated column. See more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Because the new column would be completely based on two pre-existing columns and only those two columns. SQL can do a great job maintaining this for you.

Hope this helps!